# android angularjs cordova 3.1.0 error Unknown Provider route provider

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to upgrade my android phonegap project to latest version of Cordova 3.1.0. The project is running on AngularJS. I receive the following error,

11-19 08:56:34.478: E/Web Console(366): Unknown provider: routeProvider <- route
11-19 08:56:34.478: E/Web Console(366): file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular.min.js:29 at file:///android_asset/www/lib/angular.min.js:61

Could you please help me out,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the JS file angular-route.js is missing or not loaded properly by your application. But without code it will be difficult to help you more.